# Borel measurability of almost everywhere continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose for example $f(x)=1/|x| $ for x not 0 and $f(x)=\infty$ for x=0. Is it the case that f is borel measurable in the extended sense, ie F measurable if $F\cap \mathbb(R)$ is a borel set. How do I show this function is measurable? Can I view it as a continuous function in the extended sense? I havent learned that though. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to work with the extended real line, then you must also have the extended Borel $\sigma$-algebra, namely $\overline{\mathcal{B}}$. You know that continuous functions are measurable, right? And also that the product of measurable functions are measurable right? And that the sum of measurable functions are measurable as well. Now rewrite $f$ as:
\begin{align}
f(x)=\mathbf{1}_{\{(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)\}}\frac{1}{|x|}+\infty\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{0\}}
\end{align}
This function $f$ is measurable, because it is the sum of the product of measurable functions.

Comment: Ah yes this is what I thought. Then {0} is borel as its a closed set. Thanks!

Comment: It is something that I always use: just rewrite functions as sums and products of  functions that you know are measurable. In case you wonder what $\overline{\mathcal{B}}$ is, it is just the $\sigma$-algebra generated by sets of the form $[-\infty, q]$ with $q\in\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: nice advice, thank you!